# How does one buy a burnable American flag in Tehran?

Tags: united-states, iran, protests, flag

Since 1978 I've seen footage of people in Tehran burning American flags, and as far as I can tell each time it's completely destroyed, meaning that they have to get a new American flag to burn each time.

I can't imagine that there would be an America flag store in downtown Tehran, so where are they getting all these flags?

I understand that this might not sounds like a serious question, but it is. Considering that the US is regularly denounced as a "great satan" and the government is strongly influenced by religion, I would expect that US flags and other pro-US paraphernalia would be quite hard to get ones hands on.

[image] BBC news screenshot today

Comment: Why do you assume no shops stocking international flags in such a major city?

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I've added that. If it turns out they are stocked in international shops, then that would make for a conclusive answer .

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan I suppose I could have also asked how Israeli flags are obtained; to me those would seem to be even more difficult to find.

Comment: My guess is that such flags are printed and distributed by some government-controlled Iranian propaganda organization(s), specifically for this purpose, but I can't find any source confirming this or even discussing the matter... They also burn the flag of Israel often, which would probably be even more problematic to possess in Iran otherwise.

Comment: Searching Google Maps for "flag store in Tehran, Iran" does pull up at least 20 results, but it's not clear how many of these sell *US* flags.

Comment: As you said the flags are destroyed in protests so why wouldn't there be a store selling them to meet the demand for them?

Comment: `Amazon` does not ship to Iran but `Alibaba` does. That's China, the same place where the American flags you see in the US come from.

Comment: It's just fabric, as easy to make as the clothes they are all wearing, and there's clearly a niche for them to made and sold. You could probably just reword your question to ask if there's any laws against selling/having American paraphernalia, since that would be the only reason having an abundance of American flags would be difficult.

Comment: "How does one buy a burnable Iranian flag in Tel Aviv?" I think your question is a little prejudiced.

Comment: @BjörnLindqvist it seems pretty objective to me. That this happens and ends up in the media is a fact, as the strong anti-americanism there, so I don't see any prejudice at all here, and you haven't explained why you think there is. (at)Giter's suggestion to reword seems good though.

Comment: @Giter: there might not be any explicit Iranian law prohibiting possession, but being caught with a US or Israeli flag in non-burning contexts could easily lead to one being accused of treason, spying etc.

Comment: I vote to leave this question closed, but for your information I'm from Tehran and as far as I know you could find anything in Tehran including the flags of any country including the US. Israel, or whatever (I had a pant in Iran with the US flag!). Tehran is a big city with more than 15 million people and you should know that in this crazy city you could find lots of bizarre things that is impossible to find in the US, but I can't name them cause it would lead to my account suspension!

Comment: Now I'm wondering whether it's illegal to burn a Nazi flag in Germany.

Comment: Would be interesting kind of protest to have the edible flag as well...

Comment: @Stančikas Indeed! I can think of a few other places where the government would rather *eat th neighbors governments* (assimilate, annex, repatriate etc.) than destroy them.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It's kinda funny that after seeing your post, I searched a lot and I finally found the source of those US flags in Iran. Guess what? They are completely produced in Iran just for the purpose of burning! Read it [here](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-7900545/Inside-factory-makes-flags-Iranians-BURN.html). Crazy right? I mean, I'm an Iranian and it totally freaks me out that Ayatollahs' regime spend tons of money to produce the US flags just for burning but we have lots of other essential issues in Iran that could be solved easily by that money...

Comment: It's probably a rather negligible factor in propaganda expenditures. Just all the time that people spend demonstrating around a burning flag is more valuable economically, as an opportunity cost if they did something else. Look e.g. at the policing costs for one protest in the UK https://www.met.police.uk/foi-ai/metropolitan-police/disclosure-2020/july/operational-costs-policing-protests-counter-protests-13-14-june-2020

Comment: @Fizz on the other hand, it's much easier to shrug off opportunity cost than material cost, psychologically.

Comment: How much can a US flag cost? I mean not one that would be used in the USa and is supposed to last for years while still looking good, that will cost, but one that is supposed to last a few days until it’s burned?

Answer (score 4):

It is easy to get one in Iran, even it's available on online [shopping websites](https://torob.com/p/0df63788-9631-4b2e-952c-1bbc16dd4498/%D9%BE%D8%B1%DA%86%D9%85-%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%B1%DB%8C%DA%A9%D8%A7/).

[image]

Interestingly enough we can also buy Israel and *Death to the US* flag. But it should be mentioned that in anti American demonstrations the government provides enough flags, in fact they are really expensive, on this website the cheapest American flag is 5.500.000 Rials(10$).