# Why does the Islamic Republic of Iran view the US as its principal geopolitical adversary in the world?

Tags: united-states, history, iran

No US administration has ever vowed to annihilate Iran.

American citizens don't chant anti-Iranian slogans on the streets. Iranian flags aren't being burnt in America, and there's hardly any animosity from American citizens towards the Iranian people.

The US doesn't keep Iranian hostages for no good reason.

Other than preventing the people who chant "death to America" from acquiring the capabilities to do so, has the US done anything that poses a threat to Iran?

Comment: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/69301/what-do-those-iranians-who-say-death-to-america-mean-by-it Related, you might be interested (especially the second-most-upvoted answer there as of time of writing).

Answer (score 65):

The CIA had an Iranian PM removed in a coup in 1953.  The venal, sordid and unedifying reason?  A dispute about oil royalty payments.

It also supported the Shah, which had a rather notorious secret police, all the way up to his removal in 1979.

On top of that, the faction that gained control after the revolution was a rather rabid form of Shiite Islam.

The US has sponsored a long list of sanctions against Iran, had minor armed skirmishes with it, backed its regional rivals and generally opposed it much of the time.

Last, when Iran signed the JCPOA, the USA rather unilaterally broke that deal.

US politicians vie with each other not to be called "soft on Iran".

One doesn't have to be a great fan of Iran to understand why those two don't get along.

There's a long list of [Iranian misdeeds](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/84124/21531) at the companion question but those aren't directly relevant to *why Iran doesn't like the US* except for them being two ideologically opposed systems - a nominally secular Christian democracy vs a nominally democratic Islamist dictatorship (with one of the nominals "weighing" more than the other).

p.s. My own take is that current-government Iran is a place where young women get beaten to death by the police for their choice of clothing.  So, no, this answer is not written out of great sympathy for Iran, it merely lists the reasons Iran doesn't like the US, *from the point of view of Iran, as asked in the question*.

p.p.s.  And, no, these aren't all 70 years ago events ;-)

Comment: The sanctions were in response to Iran's actions against the US, were they not?  I get it was a series of escalations (hostage taking (by Iran) -> sanctions (by the US) -> support for international terrorism and severing relations with Israel (by Iran) -> US possibly using Cold War tactics to fight Iran's proxies (by the US) ).  But, this answer makes it look like the sanctions came before Iran did anything do cause them. It's somewhat misleading if one is a priori completely unfamiliar with the chain of events.

Comment: I think it helps to view the Abadan crisis in the context of UK politics at the time.

Comment: I see that western propaganda has worked very well! I don't see the connection between the last two long (and obviously wrong) paragraphs with the question?

Comment: @C.F.G Well, what happened to those girls then?  Slipped on banana peels?  While I could admittedly be bamboozled by the eeeevil Western propaganda, local Iranian expats seem to be outraged about their deaths.  Wonder why.  Wonder why too, if Iran is so squeaky clean, it tops known executions, [at 576 in 2022](https://deathpenaltyinfo.org/policy-issues/international/executions-around-the-world), by a huge margin, next - Saudi - is only a third as many.  Only China is higher though the numbers are unknown.  And that's before population size is taken into account.

Comment: @wrod this answer ... somewhat misleading. It would be misleading on a different question than that asked which was... "Why does the Islamic Republic of Iran view". Do you think Iranians go "yes, we are under sanctions but, waitaminit, didn't we violate diplomatic protocols first?". Did **you** go and correct my linked (and UPV), answer about Iranian misdeeds: "this answer is misleading because first the US backed the Shah"? I stated Iranian grievances, as requested, no more, no less.  The facts you allude are most certainly not "unfamiliar" to the OP.  The partisanship is strong with this one

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if I have or haven't. I assume you are trying to tell me that I could have and haven't.  But, honestly, quit attributing the worst of motivations to me.  I don't correct 90% of what I see problems with.  I only drop a suggestion when I see something (1) interesting and (2) salvageable.  I haven't downvoted this question, btw.  I suggested an improvement.  If you don't like it, I understand.  But there is no reason for statements like "partisanship is strong with this one."  If you think the suggestion is not productive, you can just respectfully disagree.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica I expect most users to be as rational as possible. And ask yourself why only one period of time eg. every 10 years, Iran kills girls? Why it doesn't kill this month? See also [this CCTV](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=88yNDA7rh6E). Second, on what logic do you presuppose that the death penalty is a bad thing in all aspects? Because the EU sees it as a bad thing? If you look at its consequences, you will realize that the death penalty (although it doesn't seem good thing) is for the benefit of society.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Also note that the death penalty is only for certain crimes. e.g. Intentional murder, intent to corrupt society, drug trafficking, etc. See [this](https://quran.com/en/al-baqarah/179) and [this](https://quran.com/en/al-maidah/32) for a summary of its philosophy. It seems like propaganda or a joke that young women are beaten to death "because" of their clothes. But what is your philosophy or the EU's for not executing criminals? Doesn't the price of humanity become cheap by not executing? Because sick people argue that I kill and go to jail for a while. so easily.

Comment: @C.F.G Upvoted your answer, cuz at the end of the day it presents the Iranian view well enough, as asked.  I've listed all US issues that came to my mind, and I didn't like this Q in the first place, which is why I answered it the way I did.  But... "death penalty is only for *certain crimes* .... *intent to corrupt society*".  Most, not all, democracies have nuked death penalty.  Most of what's left is really hardcore crimes.  Singapore hangs for drugs.  We get that.  But *corrupt society*??? How arbitrary is that?  What happens if a govt you disagree with takes over?  R U "corrupting"?*

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Don't expect me to be able to explain the complicated rules and governance method of the Islamic society in this small comment. But for example, judge for yourself. Which is more criminal: being a terrorist or teaching terrorists to a group of people? A drug user or someone who sells drugs to many people? A girl who gets naked in a desert or gets naked in a crowded city? They are different and their intentions are different. All of these come from our definition of human and society.

Comment: Nah, you misunderstand my point. Stalin, Hitler, Robespierre. Revolutions eat their young.  "corrupting society" is just a license to kill anyone who disagrees with you.  And... I don't think most Muslim societies try to justify beating women to death for their clothing, in a desert or in a crowded city.  That's Iran, Afghanistan and a few others, thankfully.  So don't saddle Islam with Iran's excesses.

Answer (score 16):

> No US administration has ever vowed to annihilate Iran.

Sure, but the [current] US administration [essentially supports](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/world/biden-free-iran-anti-government-protests-mahsa-amini-rcna55624) "regime change" over there.

> “Don’t worry, we’re gonna free Iran,” President Joe Biden said [...]

Funnily enough, the previous administration--which imposed the ["strongest sanctions in history"](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-44200621)--[claimed](https://en.radiofarda.com/a/us-vows-to-up-iran-pressure-but-says-not-after-regime-change/29507258.html) they didn't want regime change, but Iran probably took actions into account louder than words. Also, during the Bush administration, the [Iran Freedom and Support Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran_Freedom_and_Support_Act) was passed--essentially funding Iranian opposition to the regime.

The (Trump era) "maximum pressure" sanctions are similar to what was imposed on North Korea (prior to Russia's invasion of Ukraine). No other countries had to move dollars by suitcases. So, expect a North Korea & Russia level of "love" for the US, just based on that.

Iranian leaders surely resent the continued US influence/presence in Iraq, which they almost certainly regard based on (Shia) religion as much closer to them--essentially their "rightful sphere of influence"--even if [officially](https://iranpress.com/iran-and-iraq-are-everlasting-friends-and-brothers) they use terms like brotherly love. (Compare with Russia's complaints about NATO/EU influence in countries on their border. Lately, Iraqi leaders [are busy](https://thehill.com/policy/defense/4426613-iraq-says-us-blatantly-violated-its-sovereignty-with-strikes-on-iran-linked-targets/) condemning 'round-the-clock both the US and Iran for violating their sovereignty.)

And Iraq is a somewhat more complicated affair than that. People sometimes forget that Iran [has had repeated conflicts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurdish_separatism_in_Iran) with Kurdish separatists who take refuge in Iraq, so in that regard the US support for the [Iraqi] Kurds in particular is resented in Iran, probably as much as Turkey resents US support for [Syrian] Kurds. (And Iraqi Kurdistan is also where most ordanced fired from Iranian land[ed], and not just recently.)

Fact of the matter is that relations have (mutually) spiraled down.

Comment: *"Don’t worry, we’re gonna free Iran,” President Joe Biden said* - Did he mean Iran or Ukraine? He [did confuse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFkSJDAazAw) those two in the past.

Comment: A regime change isn't the end (annnihilation) of a country.

Comment: @glglgl: did anyone else vow to *annihilate* Iran? If not, the biggest fish that promised "regime change" is going to be the biggest adversary (of the regime--granted the Q isn't 100% clear what they mean by "Islamic Republic of Iran".)

Comment: "The (Trump era) "maximum pressure" sanctions are similar to what was imposed on North Korea (prior to Russia's invasion" Did Russia invade North Korea? And did sanctions on NK change afterwards?

Comment: @glglgl Yes, but it is the end of the regime, so it's the a strong incentive for the people making decisions for the country to oppose the US.

Comment: @Acccumulation: I mean prior to Russia's invasion of Ukraine.

Answer (score 7):

There are multiple reasons why the Islamic Republic doesn't like the US and the West in general. Usually the role CIA played in the 1953 coup is considered as the main reason, but it isn't. The Islamic Republic doesn't like Mossadeq and the National Front either. Before the revolution they worked together to topple the Shah, after the revolution, some members of the [National Front](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Front_(Iran))(the party that was implicated in the 1953 coup), were in the government but they were soon marginalized.

#### Pahlavi dynasty:

Pahlavi dynasty reigned in Iran from 1925 to 1979 and had two monarchs: Reza shah(1925-1941) and Muhammad Reza shah(1941-1979). Reza shah, the founder of the dynasty was removed from power in 1941 when Iran was occupied by Allies during the WWII and his son Muhammad Reza became the monarch and he was a close ally of the US and the West. There were two main opposition groups under Pahlavis: communists and Islamists, communists represented intellectuals of the time and Islamists represented the mass, the majority of Iranians in a traditional conservative country.

- **1941-1963** : At the beginning, communists were the main opposition groups, they had also a political party: [Tudeh Party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tudeh_Party_of_Iran), the party was banned in 1949, because they were implicated in some assassinations. However the party continued its underground activity. In fact the shah thought that communists were the main threat, because there were many communist revolutions in 1950s such as in Cuba, Egypt and China and he underestimated the religious groups(who were also restricted under his father). The anti-American sentiment in Iran began here: the communist and left wing groups that were intellectuals and wanted to found a communist country, they talked about equality and justice and blamed the US as imperialist power.

Another factor that contributed to the anti-American sentiment was the 1953 coup. In 1953 [Mossadeq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohammad_Mosaddegh), the then prime minister wanted to restrict the power of the Shah(the monarch), things were going on well for Mossadeq and even they thought that everything was finished, but a group of Iranian generals with the support of CIA managed to change the situation, Mossadeq's government fell only after three days and he was put under house arrest. This coup intensified the anti-American sentiment among Iranian intellectuals(mainly communists).

- **1963-1979**: After 1953, political activity was restricted in Iran and Iran became a one party country. Opposition groups continued their clandestine activity, but they were not as influential, during this period, the second group- the clergy- became the main opposition in Iran. They were supported by many conservative Iranians and weren't restricted till 1963 where Khomeini started his activity as an opponent. The clergy didn't like communists, but they decided to work with them because they needed them, they needed someone to be able to analyse the world and speak with foreigners, so since then the opposition included the clergy(and the mass)and communists(intellectuals).

Anyway, they toppled the Pahlavi dynasty in 1979, and the interim government was composed of both groups: Islamists and leftists, during this period Khomeini needed those intellectuals to communicate with the world and form a new government.

#### After the revolution:

A year after the victory of the revolution, the system was working and they didn't need leftist and intellectuals any more(those who saw the US as imperialist power). They were dismissed and marginalized and were [purged](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1988_executions_of_Iranian_political_prisoners) in 1988. The Islamic Republic formed a homogenous conservative government. During this period left wing groups, main reason of anti-Americanism, weren't in the government any more, but they remained anti-American, probably because they need an enemy to blame for their failure. Anyway they need a pretext to convince their supporters. Now those who still support the Islamic Republic in Iran blame the US for economic problems caused by sanctions without knowing that the animosity began in 1979 after the [hostage crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran_hostage_crisis) by the Islamic Republic.

Besides, the Islamic Republic has other reasons to hate the US and the West: they talk about democracy, they finance media outside Iran that provide information to Iranians(who otherwise were limited to the regime's media), they give political asylum to opponents and finally they have contributed to the overthrow  of regimes in many neighbouring countries such as in Afghanistan, Iraq and Libya.

In short, the anti-American sentiment in Iran began by left wing groups and communists in 1940s, it was intensified by the coup in 1953 and was adopted by the Islamic Republic that, like all authoritarian regimes is afraid of the free world.

Comment: Frankly, an answer that blames everything on "Communists" and forgets to mention the heavy involvement of the USA in the Iraq-Iran war seems quite myopic, at best. Not to mention that opposition to the Shah was far more complex than "Islamists & Communists"

Comment: I didn't blame communism, I told they were the main opposition , and they really were. So, can you give an example of other groups? –

Answer (score 6):

There is a misunderstanding in this question which I address here:

> Americans don't chant in the streets death to …

Note that the intention of Iran is not the American people, but the government, the Senate and the actors behind the scenes of US such as lobbyists.

> No US administration has ever vowed to annihilate Iran.

AFAIK Iran never vowed to annihilate US but some of US officials and businessmen offered similar thing. [Lindsey Graham says US should bomb Iran](https://www.nbcnews.com/politics/congress/lindsey-graham-iran-escalate-war-re-coming-rcna120500) (many times). [Sheldon Adelson calls on US to nuke Iran](https://www.newsweek.com/sheldon-adelson-once-called-us-drop-nuke-iran-1560922).

> Why does the I.R. Iran view the US as its principal geopolitical adversary in the world?

### Main reason

<del>Iranians believe</del> It is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIA_activities_in_Iran) that the Mossad and the CIA supplied torture tools to [SAVAK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAVAK) (the secret police of the Shah) and trained SAVAK officers (SAVAK Formed almost 3 years after 1953 coup d'état). SAVAK's tortures were the worst and most inhumane possible and the most barbaric methods of torture the world has ever seen, which many consider to be the beginning of Iranians' hatred of US (and Israel). See [this](https://english.khamenei.ir/news/6401/SAVAK-The-most-barbaric-methods-of-torture-the-world-has-ever) and [this](https://apnews.com/article/072580b5f24b4f8ea2402221d530257e).

This is one of the important and unforgettable parts of Iran's history and for this reason the SAVAK torture center  has been turned into a [museum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Towhid_Prison) since 2002. (see also [this](https://iranparadise.com/ebrat-museum/) (graphical)) A prison museum that recalls a slice of the tragic and painful history of its prisoners for visitors by featuring the sculptures of torturers, prisoners, and different methods and devices of tortures that shock every visitor.

After Iran Revolution, and Saddam invasion of Iran, at United Nations' press conference the PM of Iran, [Mohammad Ali Rajai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mohammad-Ali_Rajai), who went to the UN directly from the war front, **displayed his bare feet on the table in front of the world's media cameras** and said (perhaps in response to a question about US hostages):

> "I was in the prisons of the Shah regime and imprisoned by [Carter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Carter) and America for two years. After four years, the effects of torture and hardships that were inflicted on me in prison are still visible on my body. For two years, I felt Carter's whips on my feet, and we are treating the hostages in the [Spy Den](https://english.khamenei.ir/news/9262/Seizure-of-US-Embassy-in-1979-Rational-or-impulsive) (US embassy) completely humanely."

After this speech, UN suspended Iran's officials from UNGA for 7 years.
Mohammad Ali Rajai was martyred in [MEK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People%27s_Mojahedin_Organization_of_Iran) terrorist group bombing.

---

Here are some important US actions against Iran:

- US military intervention to free 52 hostages in Iran (failed without Iran interfering - [Operation Eagle Claw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Eagle_Claw))
- US removed Iraq from list of State Sponsors of Terrorism  to allow US aid to Iraq; 1982. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_Sponsors_of_Terrorism_(U.S._list)#Iraq_(1979%E2%80%931982,_1990%E2%80%932004)))
- [US shot down Iranian civilian airliner (Iran Air Flight 655) in the Iranian territory; 1988.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran_Air_Flight_655)
- US Sanctions Hurt and Even Kill ['Butterfly Kids' in Iran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humanitarian_impacts_of_U.S._sanctions_against_Iran)
- US planned many coup d'état in Iran including:

  - [1953 Iranian coup d'état](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1953_Iranian_coup_d%27%C3%A9tat) (successful)
  - [2009 Color revolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1953_Iranian_coup_d%27%C3%A9tat) (failed and ended with protests)
- US directly attacked Iran by hitting Iran’s oil platforms; 1987. ([Operation Nimble Archer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Nimble_Archer))
- US funneled $5 billion of American tax payers money to Iraq; 1985-89. ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_support_for_Iraq_during_the_Iran%E2%80%93Iraq_War#Banca_Nazionale_del_Lavoro))
- US based company, Alcolac International exported mustard gas to Iraq; 1987-88. ([Halabja massacre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halabja_massacre#International_sources_for_technology_and_chemical_precursors))
- US and its allies supported "no decision" at UN on Iraq's use of chemical weapons; 1984. ([Shaking Hands with Saddam Hussein](https://nsarchive2.gwu.edu/NSAEBB/NSAEBB82/))
- US [Assassinated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassination_of_Qasem_Soleimani) [General Qasem Soleimani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qasem_Soleimani)
- US delisted MEK as a terrorist group and US officials like John Bolton and Mike Pompeo support [terrorist group MEK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People%27s_Mojahedin_Organization_of_Iran). (See also [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2018/jul/02/iran-mek-cult-terrorist-trump-allies-john-bolton-rudy-giuliani)); 2012-now
- **Iranians** certainly believe (due to many evidences e.g. [video extracted from US hacked drones by IRGC](https://www.rt.com/news/452116-iran-claims-control-us-drones/) or [US "mistakenly!" airdropped weapons for ISIS in Iraq](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2014/oct/22/isis-us-airdrop-weapons-pentagon) etc. ) that US and its allies created/trained/sponsored ISIS.
- According to the [Clinton](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-M68DS4UK4), US created the Taliban that is responsible for [killing of Iranian diplomats in Afghanistan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1998_killing_of_Iranian_diplomats_in_Afghanistan); 1998
- US spying Iran territory by [CIA spy drone RQ-170](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran%E2%80%93U.S._RQ-170_incident); 2011
- US arrested US-born Iranian reporter, [Marzieh Hashemi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marzieh_Hashemi) and forced her to remove her hijab. In detainment, she was being offered only pork; 2019
- US [seized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Press_TV#Website_domain_seizure) Iran's PressTV.com domain.
- US [blocked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fars_News_Agency#Sanctions) Iranian [Fars News Agency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fars_News_Agency) due to sanctions applied by the US Treasury; 2020.
- US unilaterally [broke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_withdrawal_from_the_Joint_Comprehensive_Plan_of_Action) the JCPOA; 2016

and etc. that is just part of US actions against Iran. There are also many other reasons e.g. Anti-Iranian Hollywood movies, supporting separatist terrorist groups, [US seizing Iranian oil cargo](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/9/8/us-confirms-seizing-iranian-oil-cargo-earlier-this-year) etc. that I think it is more than enough for Iran to  view the US as its principal adversary.

---

### Update

I accidentally found the exact same question in [CIA documents](https://www.cia.gov/readingroom/document/cia-rdp90-00552r000505290007-5):

> … **Why do so many Iranians believe in U.S. complicity, guilt?** Why do they so fervently endorse the anti-American Khomeini and the holding of the hostages? Of course, we know the embassy takeover was triggered by the Shah's entry into the U.S. last October for medical treatment. More about that later. But beyond that, **the fury in Iran focuses on the undenied fact that the CIA restored the exiled Shah to the Peacock Throne back in 1953. And after that, the Iranians have been told, the CIA helped the Shah set up SAVAK, the secret police force that has tortured so many thousands of them.** A classified Senate Foreign Relations Committee report **confirms the CIA's role in forming SAVAK.** It says the CIA provided the Shah **money**, as well as **training**, for that purpose. Of course, the brutality came later. …

Comment: Do Iranians currently feel threatened by the US? If yes please elaborate on that. Thanks.

Comment: "Iranians certainly believe that, according to the Clinton, US created the Taliban" should be sharpened. It is well-established that the US, under Carter and Reagan, supported the Taliban financially and militarily in order to oppose the Soviets in the Soviet-Afghanistan war. I doubt they actually created them, but it's unlikely they'd control Afghanistan now without US help in their starting days.

Comment: re: "Note that the intention of Iran is not the American people, but the government," Oh, no.  We do get it.  Very much so.  But, you see, we have a government by the people.

Comment: 'I see that western propaganda has worked very well! I don't see the connection between the last two long (and obviously wrong) paragraphs with the question? – 
C.F.G' If you're going to attempt to call out others about propaganda, it would be advisable for you to take great care that your own submitted answer isn't propaganda itself. If your 3rd sentence were true, there isn't much to clear up with your 2nd sentence. There are plenty of quotes of Iranian officials that call for the destruction of the US. Here's one: https://www.iranintl.com/en/202208065484

Comment: @DavidS first, that link is a Israeli-backed Persian language propaganda/TV, that interviewed Netanyahu months ago. secondly, if you can, find "Iran will Attack The US" in that article. and you will see it is a propaganda TV. Also I said "AFAIK".

Comment: @DavidS Read this https://www.iranintl.com/en/202212077198 to see how delusional the officials of that propaganda live. They talk more about their wishes than the news.

Comment: @C.F.G The link is for the quote:  Esmail Ghaani “The enemies of [Iran’s] Islamic government, led by America and the Zionist regime should know that we will never stop self-sacrifice and will move forward on the path of resistance." and “The honorable path of martyrs will be pursued until the complete destruction of the enemies of the Islamic system,” This names the US as an enemy and calls for the annihilation of the enemies. There are other links to different quotes to other Iranian officials saying similar things if you wish to dispute the above quote.

Comment: @DavidS As I said in the post, US doesn't mean US country. But in the case of Israel it is different, that means to remove anything related to the [Zionism and fascism](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/83501/26878). See also [Israel borders in Bible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promised_Land#:~:text=%22I%20will%20establish%20your%20borders,them%20or%20with%20their%20gods.) that they want to capture it.

Comment: @C.F.G We get it, "Death to America" doesn't mean "Death to Americans". People using that chant don't wish for the land to be destroyed, they wish for the entity, know as "The United States of America" to cease to exist. For there to be no more U.S. Constitution, Declaration of Independence, or Capitol Hill. That is, the destruction of the entity, the murder of its leaders and enslavement of its people, in accordance with Islam. There isn't a misunderstanding there.

Comment: @DavidS You have mixed wrong and right. Think why Iran does not chant against, for example. South Africa? Or Germany? (while Germany is responsible for selling chemical weapons to Saddam and killing thousands of Iranians). The answer is simple: there should not be any aggressors and oppressors in the world. If you consider the American people to be the reason for America's oppression, this is not my problem or Iran's. see also [Imperialism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperialism)

Comment: Presents Iranian PoV well enough.  Forgot the jet liner, Iran wouldn't.  The US cited the South Korean jet shot by the USSR for decades.  As I said, the 2 countries arent friends.

Answer (score 4):

See e.g.:

- [Iran Hostage Crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran_hostage_crisis)
- US support for Iraq in the [Iran-Iraq war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran%E2%80%93Iraq_War#U.S._involvement), which included downing an Iranian civilian aircraft with a warship that was in Iranian territorial waters
- US support for Israel, which is one of Iran's mortal enemies
- US withdrawal from the [JCPOA](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-44057306) for reasons that are considered as dubious even by many US allies
- Assassinating [Qasem Soleimani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assassination_of_Qasem_Soleimani)
- And just today, [issuing a $15 million bounty for an Iranian businessman](https://www.jpost.com/breaking-news/article-783380)

You can see a long list of mutual grievances on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran%E2%80%93United_States_relations).

Comment: Israel became an enemy to Iran somewhere after the 1979 revolution. But before that, it seems this was a friendly relationship

Comment: Israel actually assisted Iran in the Iran-Iraq war. I'd suspect Israel as an enemy of Iran is in part because the US supports Israel, beyond just the Israel-Palestine-Holy Land situation.

Comment: How is Israel Iran's "mortal enemy"? The literal meaning is someone who's trying to kill you. Iran wants to destroy Israel, but I don't think Israel bears any ill will towards Iran, other than the fact that Iran is sponsoring anti-Israel terrorism. That is, Israel's animus towards Iran is entirely a result of Iran's actions, and not any inherent opposition towards Iran.

Answer (score 1):

### Because they see the US as evil.

In addition to all the political stuff like sanctions, military actions, and spy shenanigans that hurt the Iranian people which the US has endorsed that other answers have discussed, there is an additional reason that none of the other answers have addressed: the immorality of US popular culture.

From LGBT issues to feminism, the promotion of divorce, and the destruction of traditional gender roles, the US promotes a moral stance that is fundamentally opposed to the Islamic moral code the Iranian government promotes.

Comment: Do they really? How would we know it’s not just empty talk for TV?

Comment: Meh, a US right-wing president like Trump or Bush promoted none of the stuff you mention in your 2nd para. True though, even Republicans in the US are more tolerant of gays and don't hang them from lampposts like Iran does.

Answer (score -3):

Many have posted good arguments here, I will just add that Iran has oil.

If we look at America's history of invading countries with oil and installing puppet governments so they can steal the oil, any country with oil that they don't simply hand over to the West (like Nigeria) should be a bit nervous.

Comment: stealing oil? Do you mean the US doesn't pay for the oil it gets from countries it has attacked.

Comment: The US has invaded 68 countries. Of the 68 countries, 39 (59%) have oil. In order of oil production: Saudi Arabia, Russia, Iraq, China, Iran, Kuwait, Mexico, Algeria, Angola, Oman, Libya, Colombia, Indonesia, India, Argentina, Egypt, Vietnam, Syria, Italy, Pakistan, Turkey, Sudan, Romania, Yemen, Papua New Guinea, Tunisia, Germany, Bolivia, Albania, France, Austria, Niger, Guatemala, Japan, Chile, Greece, Bulgaria, Philippines, Spain. Which ones are puppets? Source: https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/how-many-countries-has-the-us-invaded