Has the USA ever tried to change the current system of governance in Iran?
Has the USA ever tried to change the current Ayatollah-led pseudo-democratic government system in Iran?
If so, why are they not succeeding?
If no, why not?

You mean like the US support for Iraq in the Iran-Iraq war? This question is very vague. Do you mean since 1979, and what methods of persuasion are you interested in?


Has the USA ever tried to change the current Ayatollah-led pseudo-democratic government system in Iran?

Kind of. They allocated some funds to Iranian opposition e.g. during the Bush years. Possibly later too, but might have been less overtly.
Aside/BTW, the Trump "maximum pressure" campaign, mostly based on sanctions, ostensibly was not for regime change, just policy change.


If so, why are not they succeeding?

From what we know, these were relatively small sums, e.g. $10 million in that Iran Freedom and Support Act.
Also, Iran has yet to suffer the kind of catastrophic defeats that Israel's Arab neighbors have, which did result in regime-changing themselves at least to some degree [i.e. vis-a-vis Israel], albeit with some US encouragement and possibly support.
If you take Egypt for example, it receives billions in US aid (used to be 2nd after Israel in terms of US aid for years, until the Ukraine war threw those stats out the window.) It's not so much regime change that matters than follow-through in supporting a friendly regime (or at least more friendly than plausible alternatives).
Small-budget "regime change" efforts have succeeded sometimes, see e.g. Milosevic, but then one should not overemphasize how much that really changed Serbia: it's still stuck in a sort of half-way house between Russian and EU influence.
And (as some of owari's answer hints), the system and leadership of the Islamic Republic make a Milosevic-type approach less likely to succeed: candidates are [officially] vetted by the leadership, demonstrators are more often shot etc.

[Iranian Viewpoint]
Yes, sure they have tried, like Imam Khamenei has repeatedly said they have tried whatever they could, but with no real success. For example:

The fight is not about some political issues. Well, any two countries
may have differences with each other on issues that they can settle by
negotiating; and and put an end to it. However, the problem of the
Islamic Republic and the arrogant American government is not alike.
The problem is of another kind. The problem is more fundamental here.
The problem is that the regime of the United States of America
claimed, after World War II, to be the world's absolute superpower ...
In the middle of the West Asia, Iran was located; which was then a
main regional base for them. Around Iran, there were different
countries, each of which was more or less under the control of the
United States. Of course, the Soviets had made intrusions during this
period, but the Americans had the upper hand and this routine had to
continue ... In the midst of this ever-increasing arrogant authority
and at a most sensitive point, the Islamic Revolution was born in
Iran, and the most important slogan of this revolution was to confront
oppression and arrogance; It was to defend the rights of nations. The
Islamic revolution took this main region, i.e. Iran, out of the
control of America. One day, the Americans had people in your country
Iran, in your Tehran, in different regions of the country, in all
sensitive places, in the armed forces, in the departments related to
finance and property, in the sensitive departments of politics, in the
security departments, their agents and people were versatile. The king
himself, who was the head of all the country's institutions and used
to interfere in all affairs, used to listen to the American and
British ambassadors. If they wanted something and insisted on it, Shah
inevitably obeyed no matter if he wanted it or not. Sometimes he
didn't want to, but he had to obey and so he obeyed. From such a
region, the Americans were expelled. Well, this was a very important
incident, This was no small wound.
...
America was the first government that started to oppose this movement
of the people seriously. [Of course] there were other governments who
were similarly very unhappy with the situation that happened in Iran,
but they did not show such a bold reaction. In the first months of the
victory of the revolution, the US Senate issued a strong resolution
against the Islamic Republic of Iran. The US practically started
hostilities. This was while the American embassy in Iran was still
open! Those who think that the relationship with America, friendship
with America will make people safe from America's harm, refer to this
historical experience. The American embassy was still open in Iran,
the Americans could travel easily inside the country, the revolution
had not caused them to expel the Americans from Iran. Like other
governments, they had embassies and agents. They were living here. At
such a time, the American government showed its hostility toward the
revolution.
...
America's goal is to regain the control it had over this country
during the Shah period. This domination was lost with the Islamic
revolution, its hand was shortened. The purpose of this imposition of
war, and imposition of embargo, and political and economic pressures,
and the like, was to return this domination, but it failed. The US has
been trying this for forty years and has not been able to get anywhere
in this regard.
...
We have seen an enemy in front of us from the beginning of the
revolution until today. From the first hours of the revolution this
enemy appeared, became present and started opposing, and this enemy
was the government of the United States of America. From the very
beginning --of course, when they recovered from their initial
confusion and those days when they didn't know what was happening
passed-- they started to oppose, to oppose. Till now that we are
talking Today, the Americans have carried out all kinds of hostilities
and various ruse and tricks to attack the Islamic Republic, that is,
you cannot probably name any opposition that they have not already
done towards the Islamic Republic. They organized a military coup,
incited the ethnic groups, incited Saddam to go to war with Iran and
attack Iran, Later during the war they supported him in all kinds of
ways, they boycotted us, they exerted influence against us in the
United Nations, they advertised against us every noon and night, they
used art, they used Hollywood to make movies against us, and did that
not only for one or two times, they made military moves at different
times, they shot down our civilian plane over the Persian Gulf, some
of our centers in the Persian Gulf were attacked, They did all sorts
of things against the Islamic Republic: security, political, economic,
advertising, cultural objections, all sorts of things. The purpose of
all these works was subversion. Now [that] today this notion is
expressed explicitly by the American officials, it is nothing new,
This was their goal from the first day. Even the same president [i.e.,
Obama] who repeated and insisted that our goal was not to overthrow,
his goal was to overthrow, and this meaning became completely clear
later.
[source in Persian, compiled from several different speeches
there to clarify further the context]

Also,

This [enemy, the US] is in front of us, it does its best, spends money
a lot, and plans a lot, putting all its efforts in dividing people
inside Iran [this is a well-known politics in Iran about how the UK
was accustomed to go by: "divide and rule"], whether making bold
the political divisions, the religious divisions, the ethnic
differences, or language differences. These rich governments around
our country that are also tricked to grab their monies and resources,
are asked for assistance so they can do things against our country as
well. They do whatever they can, [but] by the God's grace, their
noses are rubbed in the dirt, and they should know that we will
continue to move forward with strength. God willing, we will
disappoint America in all aspects. Those who used to be at the head of
the American government were not staying back doing nothing, they also
worked a lot. Reagan was both stronger and wiser than Trump, he
actually took action against us, with threats and so much noise in the
media. He was a film actor, so that his acting was even better than
this one [i.e.Trump], he actually acted against us and they shot down
our plane and they did that job. But where is Reagan now? Where is the
Islamic Republic now? Today, the Islamic Republic has progressed and
grown several times since Reagan's time, in all aspects. Reagan is now
caught in divine punishment, his body is rotted and soiled, and his
soul, according to the rules we believe in, is busy repaying back to
the divine justice system. This new government will not be any
different. The Islamic Republic will remain afloat by God's grace, and
they will never reach their wish in which the Islamic Republic is
weakened or withdrew from the field. [source in Persian]

But why the US with all its ingenious politicians, planners, and scenario writers, technological advances, and etc., yet fails to gain from Iran what it likes? Simply, because a fundamental teaching of Islam is the need to acquire the knowledge about the enemy of the divine religions, the Satan. If Imam Khomeini, the late supreme leader of the Islamic Republic of Iran and the founder of it, once coined the label "great Satan" to the US, it was not out of anger or hatred, but on a firm ground of knowledge about who Satan is and what his methodology is to reach its goals. Imam Khomeini was a great Shia Muslim scholar and not a regular politician, many Islamic scholars still teach Imam's Islamic theories to new students. We are told a lot about the Satan in Quran and Ahadeeth, and also about the methodologies he has used against the humanity during the past several thousands years. The US government is a really good fit for being a great Satan in how it works, according to how we understand the issues. As a simple example, one thing that we know from Islam is to not let the Satan get close to us, as even simply hearing to it can easily make many regular politicians to be deviated from the right path. Imam Khamanei once addressed this issue by:

I am very concerned [about negotiating with America]. This concern is
caused by the fact that the other party is extremely prone to
deception and lies, breaching promises, and moving in the opposite
direction; the other side is like this. An example happened in this
case; After our negotiators finished their negotiations, after a few
hours the statement of the White House was published explaining the
negotiations. This statement they published --which they call a "fact
sheet"-- is often against the truth. That is, the narrative they offer
about the negotiations and the understandings that have been made is a
distorted, false and untrue narrative... Of course, I was never
optimistic about negotiations with America. Not because of an illusion
but because of experience. We have experienced it.
...
The rationality is that a person should respond to such an enemy with
wisdom, with tact, with caution, by not being deceived, by not
approaching the field of her conspiracy, by not entering the field
that she has drawn, with these precautions.
...
They say that we want to solve our problems with Iran... They say that
we want to negotiate and solve our problems with Iran. this is what
they say, but in practice, they engage in sanctions, they engage in
false propaganda, they say inappropriate things, they constantly
spread false information regarding the Islamic Republic of Iran and
the people of Iran... American statesmen talk illogically. With an
illogical interlocutor, one cannot sit and talk relying on logic ...
Well, he is unreasonable. Irrational means pushy, it means talking
nonsense. This is a fact that we have found clear during these thirty
years in dealing with various global issues. We understand who is on
the other side and how to treat him.
...
In this issue, in the issues related to the region, in the various
issues that we have, in the problems that we have with America and the
likes of America, it cannot be solved by negotiation, We have to
choose a path ourselves, and go that way... Our political and
diplomatic officials say frankly that the Americans want to take
everything, [but] not give anything! [If] you take one step back, they
will take one step forward ... The problem of negotiation is: ... when
you negotiate, it means you give one point, take another point; This
is the meaning of negotiation ... He takes from you what you should
give, [but] he doesn't give you what he should give, he bullies,
that's what arrogance means, global arrogance means that, it means
bullying, thinking oneself superior, not sticking to one's word, not
taking any responsibility. This is the meaning of arrogance. He breaks
his promises. Well, our honorable Imam said: America is the great
devil. This interpretation is really a wonderful interpretation.
Almighty God narrates the words of Satan that Satan will say to those
who obeyed him on the Day of Judgment: Indeed, Allah had promised you the promise of truth. And I promised you, but I betrayed you. Satan
tells his followers that God had given you a truthful promise, you did
not follow God's promise, you did not abide by it; but I gave you a
false promise, and you followed me! I broke my promise, I promised you
and I broke it; Satan blames his followers like this in the Day of
Judgment. Then God Almighty says about the words of the devil that he
tells them: So do not blame me, but blame yourselves. This is
exactly the case with America today. Now Satan is saying this in the
Day of Resurrection, Americans are saying this in the world today.
They promise, they don't act, they violate. They take the credit
score, they don't give the credit score. This is the situation with
America.
[source in Persian]

This was one aspect of the issue ... Identifying the US and the global arrogance system as the great Satan, Iran has a rich school of thought and great many resources on how to withstand US and yet defeat it even if it is apparently a superpower.
So in essence, Iran has identified the US as the great Satan, and being familiar with how Satan works according to Islamic teachings, Iran knows what is going on behind the scene and is not deceived by US designed plans, so has always found the right path to survive

"really good fit for being a great Satan in how it works" -- I guess that's the essence of this answer. The leadership of the Islamic Republic can't assume the US plans anything less. TBH this sounds like an answer to a slightly diff question though. https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/84248/why-does-the-islamic-republic-of-iran-view-the-us-as-its-principal-geopolitical

@IVFcomesfromthetip, Iran has identified the US as the great Satan, and being familiar with how Satan works according to Islamic teachings, Iran knows what is going on behind the scene and is not deceived by US designed plans, so has always found the right path to survive. This is a better essence of the answer IMH, as your summary does not contain the answer to "why are they [the US] not succeeding?".

Ok, maybe you should emphasize that part.

@IVFcomesfromthetip, thank you for your suggestion, added an addendum to the end.

The answer is no. Despite the Islamic Republic's animosity towards the US, the American government hasn't engaged in any official or serious effort to change the regime in Iran yet. There have been situations in which Iran and the US were on the brink of war or when tensions were very high, but the United States showed that, despite favorable opportunities, it didn't have any intention to change the regime.

In 1979, nine months after the Islamic Revolution, the Iranian regime took American diplomats hostage. In April 1980, the US tried to release the hostages in a limited operation called Eagle Claw. The operation failed, and the US didn't pursue a more extensive offensive. Given the unstable situation in Iran after the revolution, the regime was very vulnerable.

Operation Praying Mantis: After Iran mined an American warship in the Persian Gulf, the US launched a retaliatory attack, destroying many of Iran's naval assets in April 1988. This battle took place towards the end of the Iran-Iraq War. After eight years of war, the US could have easily overthrown the regime.

After the 9/11 attacks, the US tried to change the Middle East. It changed the regimes in Afghanistan (2001) and Iraq (2003), Iran's eastern and western neighbors, and President Bush designated Iran as part of the Axis of Evil in 2002, along with North Korea and Iraq. After the invasion of Iraq in 2003, it was assumed that Iran would be the next target, but it didn't happen.

In 2009, during the widespread demonstrations in Iran, known as the Green Movement, some American senators, like J. McCain, proposed supporting the movement and regime change. However, the then US government opted for negotiating with the regime, and these negotiations led to the JCPOA.

On January 2020, after the assassination of Iranian general, Qassim Soleimani, Iran and the US were close to a direct confrontation but nothing happened.


But why didn't the US try to change the regime? It is difficult to say. I think the US and the West in general supported Iran after the Second World War, mainly because they needed a strong ally against the Soviet Union in the region. After 1979, they didn't try to change the regime because:

After the Islamists seized power in 1979, they understood that Iran wasn't going to become a Soviet ally, so they didn't need regime change. After 1991 and the fall of the USSR, this danger was completely removed.

From 1991 to 2011, the Islamic Republic wasn't a major problem. They organized some terrorist attacks, like in Lebanon in 1983 with the help of their proxies, without assuming responsibility.

After 2011, the US decided to reduce its presence in the Middle East. This was the beginning of the Syrian revolution. Iran began its expansionist adventures and sent troops to Syria from 2012 to quell protests. After 2015, when the Syrian regime used chemical weapons and crossed what the US had declared as a red line, Iran became emboldened, and after a while, Russia entered the scene, making things more complicated.


In short, the US has not supported any regime change in Iran since 1979 despite constant tensions, and the reason is probably that they didn't see the need for it and thought the consequences of such attempts would outweigh the benefits. Anyway, the US doesn't have good experiences with intervention in Iran. The 1953 coup d'etat and negotiations with Khomeini shortly before the revolution in 1979 have long been the subject of criticism.

You omit that one needs a viable opposition to support to foster a regime change. Then, like Ukraine, you can foment a civil war to do it. But no Iranian can support the US publicly after the harm the Americans have done to the Iranian state, over the decades, with their sanctions and military attacks, with Israel. It is highly unlikely that any politician who speaks in favour of US will politically survive there. That means the only option to do a regime change is to militarily defeat Iran. And that's what the US has been trying - weakening Iran till it can't militarily defend itself.

Did they have a viable alternative for Afghanistan or Iraq? But they did it. Besides,  I live in Iran and Most Iranians have more positive view of the US. Yes some 50 years ago things were different, but Iranians who criticize the US because of the 1953 coup, or who think that the US has cased harm to Iran are really rare. Personally I think the US- Iran alliance from 1941 to 1979 was very constructive for Iran.

@TMFG, Did they have a viable alternative for Afghanistan or Iraq? But they did it. --- those weren't regime changes. Those were invasions. Invasion and regime-change are not the same things.

@TMFG, Yes some 50 years ago things were different, but Iranians who criticize the US because of the 1953 coup, or who think that the US has cased harm to Iran are really rare. Personally I think the US- Iran alliance from 1941 to 1979 was very constructive for Iran. --- Probably, you live in utopian Iran. Try to get closer to the Mullahs, you will see different pictures.

@user366312 yes, but mullahs aren't popular at all. They are really unpopular.

@TMFG Did they have a viable alternative for Afghanistan or Iraq? No, they didn't and that is why they had to invade the country to do a regime change. That is exactly what they are going to do with Iran too. The hope is that economic sanctions will weaken Iran's military, like it is did with Iraq's, and then some flimsy excuse like "WMDs" will be used to invade Iran.

@sfxedit Maybe, but Iran's economy is really devastated. Iran is sanctioned since 1979 and sanctions are really hard after 2015. Antway mullah find some money to make some missiles, for them nothing is important but their missiles. And in other domains Iran' s army is a disaster, air planes date back to 1970s without having access to spare part. Iran's military is based on propaganda not reality. That's why they created all this proxy groups to threaten other countries if there is a war.

Plus the largest stockpile of ballistic missiles in the Middle East, allegedly. Although that seems to be a paper tiger, unless (all) aimed at a city. Which would pretty much guarantee a less flimsy reason to invade. The real threat is their promise to shoot at all ships in the Gulf. The US doesn't really want that [right now] because China would buy more Russian oil then. But if the US strat for Ukraine were to change in the direction that JD Vance wants...

Despite the resentment against Iranian politicians, nationalism in Iran is too strong to welcome any US invasion into Iran to get rid of the current Islamic rulers of Iran. That, and the absence of a viable pro-western opposition is why the US has not been able, and will not be able to in the near future, do a regime change in Iran.

@sfxedit I cannot predict how the exact reaction of Iranians would be. But I am sure that most of Iranians won't risk for fighting for this regime. The Islamic Republic has occupied Iran, it recruited Lebanese and Palestinian mercenaries to kill Iranian protesters.  Why should Iranians risk their lives for such regime.

@IVFcomesfromthetip If the Iranian ballistic missiles weren't a threat, US wouldn't be deploying a Terminal High Altitude Area Defense (THAAD) battery to Israel. Iran's recent attack exposed this weakness in Israel's missile shield.

@sfxedit: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/57370/did-iranian-missile-strikes-on-israel-destroy-any-number-of-f-35s

@IVFcomesfromthetip You missed the whole point of my comment - if the Iranian ballistic missiles weren't a real threat to Israel, the US wouldn't be deploying a billion dollar THAAD system to protect Israel from such ballistic missiles. The reality is that ballistic missiles are hard to catch for missile shields, and the hits on the ground show that Iranian missiles managed to penetrate the Iron Dome successfully. Here's a more comprehensive analysis IMINT: Iran’s Strike on Nevatim Airbase (which was also cited in the Guardian article I linked to).

@IVFcomesfromthetip If Iran had targeted these missiles on populated Israeli cities, they would have caused a lot of "collateral damage" (I hate that word).

@sfxedit: Biden is under domestic electorate pressure to show he's doing more for Israel. Even if the THAADs will catch only a handful of extra missiles in a big incoming salvo. The severity of the threat to hardened military infrastructure proved rather low. "Big, fat" civilian targets would be another matter. That's also what I meant with my 1st comment you were replying to, BTW.

@IVFcomesfromthetip True. (That, and maybe also sales-pitch demo to entice Israel, and other Arab countries, to buy a few of these billion dollar THAAD systems). It would be really interesting to see the real-world performance of a THAAD battery against a salvo of 100's of ballistic missiles and drone, especially the high-end one's made to avoid such missile defence systems.

@sfxedit I have been curious about the effectiveness of THAAD systems for awhile. I recall that they were used by South Korea, well, they were sent there but maybe not used, in 2014 or so. I haven't heard anything about them since in the media until now. Just an idea, as something to check. I should, and just provide a link!
